# SELECT CASE with Alias in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a stored Procedure that I cant get to work:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetBrands
@sortColumn INT
AS
SELECT          DISTINCT(tblBrand.BrandID),             
                tblBrandinCategory.CategoryID,
                tblBrand.BrandName AS Brand, 
                AVG(tblReview.Grade) AS AverageGrade,  
                COUNT(tblReview.ReviewID) AS Review

FROM            tblBrand LEFT JOIN
                            tblBrandinCategory ON tblBrand.BrandID = tblBrandinCategory.BrandID LEFT JOIN
                            tblReview ON tblBrand.BrandID = tblReview.BrandID

GROUP BY tblBrand.BrandID, tblBrandinCategory.CategoryID, tblBrand.BrandName

ORDER BY
CASE 
WHEN @sortColumn = 1 THEN Brand
WHEN @sortColumn = 2 THEN Review
WHEN @sortColumn = 4 THEN AverageGrade
ELSE Brand
END
```

The result that I want to have is a list with brands, that only will be displayed once. The tblBrandInCategory messes that up for me.

```
tblBrand
BrandID    BrandName
1          Nike
2          Adidas
3          Puma

tblCategory
CategoryID   CategoryName
1            Shoes
2            Shorts
3            Pants

tblBrandInCategory
CategoryID    BrandID   
1             1
2             1
3             1

tblReview
ReviewID      Grade    BrandID
1             5        1
2             9        1 
3             2        1
```

I get the result multiplyed with three becouse BrandID 1 exist 3 times in tblBrandInCategoiry.

Another problem is that in the ORDER BY CASE I get errors that AverageGrade is not recognizable, but tblReview.Grade is fine, but I want to order it on the Average Grade.

Comment: I think you need to edit your question.  tblReview, in your query, isn't in the schema you list underneath.

Comment: I added the schema for tblReview

Comment: As you saidd "I get the result multiplyed with three becouse BrandID 1 exist 3 times in tblBrandInCategoiry." PLease update your expected resultset as well.

Comment: If there is 1 ReviewID in tblReview I want "COUNT(tblReview.ReviewID) AS Review" to be 1. Now becouse BrandID 1 Exist three times in tblBrandInCategory I get the Count Result to 3 when it should be 1.

Comment: can you show the final resultset screenshot as well plz ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7245/discussion-between-stackoverflow-user-and-user1007103)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Another problem is that in the ORDER BY CASE I get errors that
>   AverageGrade is not recognizable, but tblReview.Grade is fine, but I
>   want to order it on the Average Grade.

AverageGrade can not be used as a column to sort until your main query is the Sub Query....

> I get the result multiplyed with three becouse BrandID 1 exist 3 times
>   in tblBrandInCategoiry.

```
create table #tblBrand
(
BrandID    int,
BrandName varchar(10)
)

create table #tblCategory
(
CategoryID       int,
CategoryName varchar(10)
)

create table #tblBrandInCategory
(
CategoryID       int,
BrandID int
)

create table #tblReview
(
ReviewID             int,
Grade    int,
BrandID int
)

insert into #tblBrand(BrandID, BrandName)values(1, 'Nike')
insert into #tblBrand(BrandID, BrandName)values(2, 'Adidas')
insert into #tblBrand(BrandID, BrandName)values(3, 'Puma')



insert into #tblCategory(CategoryID, CategoryName)values(1, 'Shoes')
insert into #tblCategory(CategoryID, CategoryName)values(2, 'Shorts')
insert into #tblCategory(CategoryID, CategoryName)values(3, 'Pants')

insert into #tblBrandInCategory(CategoryID, BrandID)values(1, 1)
insert into #tblBrandInCategory(CategoryID, BrandID)values(2, 1)
insert into #tblBrandInCategory(CategoryID, BrandID)values(3, 1)


insert into #tblReview(ReviewID, Grade, BrandID)values(1, 5, 1)
insert into #tblReview(ReviewID, Grade, BrandID)values(2, 5, 9)
insert into #tblReview(ReviewID, Grade, BrandID)values(3, 2, 1)


Select BrandID, Brand, AverageGrade, Review
From
(
SELECT          DISTINCT(#tblBrand.BrandID),             
                --#tblBrandinCategory.CategoryID,
                #tblBrand.BrandName AS Brand, 
                AVG(#tblReview.Grade) AS AverageGrade,  
                COUNT(#tblReview.ReviewID) AS Review

FROM            #tblBrand 
                LEFT JOIN #tblBrandinCategory ON #tblBrand.BrandID = #tblBrandinCategory.BrandID 
                LEFT JOIN #tblReview ON #tblBrand.BrandID = #tblReview.BrandID

GROUP BY #tblBrand.BrandID, #tblBrandinCategory.CategoryID, #tblBrand.BrandName
)K
ORDER BY
CASE 
WHEN @sortColumn = 1 THEN Brand
WHEN @sortColumn = 2 THEN Review
WHEN @sortColumn = 4 THEN AverageGrade
ELSE Brand

drop table #tblBrand
drop table #tblCategory
drop table #tblBrandInCategory
drop table #tblReview
```

**Final Resultset**

[image]

Comment: Okey, is there another way to order on Average Grade?

Comment: Thank you very mutch! Works great! Now I just have to figure the Order By, but this is great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just edit the SELECT to leave off tblBrandInCategory results:

```
SELECT tblBrand.BrandID,                              
     tblBrand.BrandName AS Brand,
     AVG(tblReview.Grade) AS AverageGrade, 
     COUNT(tblReview.ReviewID) AS Review 
FROM tblBrand 
     --tblBrandinCategory isn't even needed for what you're doing
     --LEFT JOIN tblBrandinCategory ON tblBrand.BrandID = tblBrandinCategory.BrandID 
     LEFT JOIN tblReview ON tblBrand.BrandID = tblReview.BrandID 
GROUP BY tblBrand.BrandID, tblBrand.BrandName
```

This would need to be edited further to account for null joins, where a grade does not exist (maybe with AVG(ISNULL(tblReview.Grade, 0))).  Depends on your requirements.

Comment: Okey, I stil get the result muliplyed. COUNT(tblReview.ReviewID) AS Review is three times more then it should be.

Comment: I think what you are saying is that you get three rows for that Brand.  I updated my answer when I realized you didn't need to join against tblBrandinCategory at all.  That should fix your result set.

Comment: That works great, but I need to join that tabel aswell becouse I need the CategoryID, sorry I did not mention that.

Comment: you can check the another answer now.